# Find shortest path between list of nodes in single query Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have two lists

```
['avia', 'paul', 'tom']

['james','bond']
```

I am tring to find the shortes path between

```
avia -> james
paul -> james
tom -> james
avia -> bond
paul -> bond
tom -> bond
```

i create the query with in two loops and query neo4j every time
so multiple calls are being made to neo4j. is ther a way to creat this in one stored procedure and make only one call to neo4j. sample query is like below

```
match p = allShortestPaths((a{name:'avia'})-[*..2]-(b {name:'james'})) return p
```

Comment: I solved using the below query
UNWIND ['avia', 'paul', 'tom'] AS person
 UNWIND ['james','bond'] AS person2
  match p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*..2]-(b))
  WHERE a.name = person and b.name = person2
  unwind relationships(p) as rels 
  return person,person2, collect(distinct type(rels))

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the `UNWIND` function to unwind your initial collection, like below.

```
WITH 'james' AS start_point,  ['avia', 'paul', 'tom'] AS end_points
UNWIND end_points as e
match p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*..2]-(b)) 
WHERE a.name = start_point and b.name = e
return start_point, p
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the second array can also have multiple values, I will update the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can unwind the list of start nodes like this :

```
UNWIND ['avia','paul','tom'] AS person
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((a {name: person})-[*..2]-(b {name: "james"}))
RETURN person, collect(p)
```

this will return you 3 rows (assuming a path is found) being

```
person, collection of paths found
```

Moreover, please use labels!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way should be just to match both start and end nodes using index lookups (via property membership within your list parameters) for both, then running shortestPath. Something like this, but with parameterized inputs:

```
WITH ['avia', 'paul', 'tom'] as startNames, ['james','bond'] as endNames
MATCH (start:Person), (end:Person)
WHERE start.name in startNames and end.name in endNames
MATCH p=allShortestPaths((start)-[*..2]-(end))
RETURN p
```

You'll want to have an index on :Person(name) (or on whatever equivalent you're using) so these utilize index lookups